# Mapping 2D coordinates to 3D plane using only CSS (like Mario Kart/Mode 7 )?

Tags: javascript, css, 3d

I'm attempting to add a 2D element onto a "3D" plane. I've added the element (kart) to where it should go (the red square). As you pan around with the sliders and change the angle, the red square shifts correctly (as it's placed within the same div that is skewed using css)

My intention is for the kart to scale similarly to the red square. I was hoping that I could either use css directly to do this, or to leverage css to determine the size and coordinates of the red square in order to place the 2D kart.

I did find `getBoundingClientRect` but I couldn't figure out how to successfully use the values in there.

Any ideas?

```js
var kart = {
  x: 130,
  y: 513,
  angle: 0
};

var viewport = {
  width: 512,
  height: 174
};


var redraw = function() {
  var translate = {
    x: -(kart.x - (viewport.width / 2)),
    y: -(kart.y - (viewport.height / 2))
  };
  translate.y += 60; // Move focus of camera

  var style = "transform: ";
  style += "translate(" + translate.x + "px, " + translate.y + "px) ";
  style += "rotateX(76deg) ";
  style += "rotateZ(" + kart.angle + "deg) ";

  style += "scaleX(2.5) scaleY(2.5);"; // Attempt to get sizing closer to original
  style += "transform-origin: " + kart.x + "px " + kart.y + "px;"

  $("#inner").attr("style", style);

  var kartPositionOffset = $("#kartposition").offset();
  var viewportOffset = $("#viewport").offset();

  var rect = $("#kartposition")[0].getBoundingClientRect();
  //var height = rect.height;

  var height = 32,
    width = 32; // These need to be dynamically changed

  var x = (kartPositionOffset.left - viewportOffset.left);
  var y = (kartPositionOffset.top - viewportOffset.top);

  $("#kart").css({
    left: x + "px",
    top: y + "px",
    height: height + "px",
    width: width + "px"
  });
};


$(document).ready(function() {
  var $viewport = $("#viewport");

  $viewport.css({
    width: viewport.width + "px",
    height: viewport.height + "px"
  });

  $("#kartposition").css({
    left: (kart.x - 8) + "px",
    top: (kart.y - 8) + "px"
  });

  redraw();

  var onSlide = function(event, ui) {
    var index = $(this).data("index");
    kart[index] = ui.value;
    redraw();
  };

  $("#vertical").slider({
    slide: onSlide,
    max: 1024,
    value: kart.y
  });

  $("#horizontal").slider({
    slide: onSlide,
    max: 1024,
    value: kart.x
  });

  $("#angle").slider({
    slide: onSlide,
    min: -360,
    max: 360,
    value: kart.angle
  });
});
```

```css
#kart {
  display: block;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/ga8Cl.png');
  left: 256px;
  top: 35px;
  z-index: 100000;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

#kartposition
{
  background:red;width:16px;height:16px;position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="viewport" style="perspective: 256px;overflow:hidden;position:relative;">
  <div id="inner">
    <div id="kartposition"></div>
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/NuZJa.png">
  </div>

  <div id="kart">
  </div>
</div>

<table style="width:400px;">
<tr><td style="width:1%">X</td><td><div id="horizontal" data-index="x"></div></td></tr>
<tr><td>Y</td><td><div id="vertical" data-index="y"></div></td></tr>
<tr><td>Angle</td><td><div id="angle" data-index="angle"></div></td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I found that overflow set to any value other than visible can force it to be flat. You have overflow: hidden on your viewport. I’m on mobile so can’t test it right now but that may work. Here’s the link https://css-tricks.com/things-watch-working-css-3d/

Comment: @JeremyBerchtold Probably better for you to see the demo...